# How to exclude columns under different conditions in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

here my example:

```
TR1    COR2   DR3   VAR1 VAR2 P

0,1    0,3    0,23  10    12  3
0,2    0,4    0,45  12    13  0
```

Here my doubt, The best way to make a confition that if it finds some value of p = 3, it has to eliminate the 3 first columns, if there is no P = 3 but if it is found P = 2 to eliminate the 2 first columns, but there is no P = 3 neither P = 2, but if you find P = 1 remove the first column

If my table is:

```
TR1    COR2   DR3   VAR1 VAR2 P

0,1    0,3    0,23  10    12  3
0,2    0,4    0,45  12    13  2
```

The results have to look like this:

```
                   VAR1  VAR2 P

                    10    12  3
                    12    13  2
```

If my table is:

```
    COR2   DR3   VAR1 VAR2 P

    0,3    0,23  10    12  2
    0,4    0,45  12    13  1
```

The results have to look like this:

```
                   VAR1  VAR2 P

                    10    12  2
                    12    13  1
```

If my table is:

```
       DR3   VAR1 VAR2 P

       0,23  10    12  1
       0,45  12    13  0
```

The results have to look like this:

```
                   VAR1  VAR2 P

                    10    12  1
                    12    13  0
```

Comment: I think You need to check `df1[-seq_len(df1$P[df1$P > 0][1])]`

Comment: thanks, but this eliminates rows not columns

Comment: I would suggest you to check the data.frame indexing with inbuilt dataset `mtcars[-(1:3)]`

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to get the first non-zero number in 'P' and use that to remove the columns

```
df1[-seq_len(df1$P[df1$P > 0][1])]
#  VAR1 VAR2 P
#1   10   12 2
#2   12   13 1
```

It can be wrapped into a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, colNm) {
       dat[-seq_len(dat[[colNm]][dat[[colNm]] >0][1])]
 }

f1(df1, "P")
#  VAR1 VAR2 P
#1   10   12 2
#2   12   13 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this eliminates rows not columns.

Comment: @Lectxx7 If it is a data.frame, then by default without using a `,`, it recognizes the index as column index.  But, if it is a matrix, you may need a `,`.  You can check `mtcars[-(1:3)]`

Comment: this is a data.table.

Comment: @Lectxx7  Ohh, in that case, you need `as.data.table(mtcars)[, -(1:3), with = FALSE]`

Comment: sorry again, but how to apply for u data.table with name df1?

Comment: @Lectxx7  It would be `df1[, -seq_len(df1$P[df1$P > 0][1]), with = FALSE]`

Comment: Thanks for your support, but are there a possibility to eliminate considering the value of P? if P=3 eliminate 3 columns.

Comment: @Lectxx7  The function picks up the first non zero element of P and eliminate based on that value.  If the value is 3, it would remove 1:3 columns